# Research Explicit Runge-Kutta method / How to find stability function?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, stability

I have this initial conditions

```
DAE = ( {
{Derivative[1][Subscript[y, 1]][x] == -99*Subscript[y, 1][x] + 
   250*Subscript[y, 2][x]},
{Derivative[1][Subscript[y, 2]][x] == 
  40*Subscript[y, 1][x] - 99*Subscript[y, 2][x]}} );
INIT = ( {
    {Subscript[y, 1][0] == A},
    {Subscript[y, 2][0] == B}
   } );
```

Eigenvectors and eigenvalues is {5,2}, {-5,2}, 1, -199 respectively.
For this example we can set

```
A = 10;
B = 4;
```

I use NDSolveValue:

```
NSolution = NDSolveValue[{DAE, INIT}, {Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2]}, {x,0,1}, Method -> ClassicalRungeKutta, StartingStepSize -> 1/100];
```

Where ClassicalRungeKutta is:

```
ClassicalRungeKutta /: 
  NDSolve`InitializeMethod[ClassicalRungeKutta, __] := 
  ClassicalRungeKutta[];
ClassicalRungeKutta[___]["Step"[f_, t_, h_, y_, yp_]] := 
  Block[{deltay, k1, k2, k3, k4},
   k1 = yp;
   k2 = f[t + 1/2 h, y + 1/2 h k1];
   k3 = f[t + 1/2 h, y + 1/2 h k2];
   k4 = f[t + h, y + h k3];
   deltay = h (1/6 k1 + 1/3 k2 + 1/3 k3 + 1/6 k4);
   {h, deltay}
   ];
```

So now it works correct in that case to solve DAE. But here is a very little detail that can broke all solution. And it is:

```
StartingStepSize -> 1/100
```

If we set StartingStepSize less than 1/65 we can see the increasing difference between analytic and numeric solution

```
ASolution = DSolveValue[ {DAE, INIT}, {Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2]}, {x, 0,1}]
y1analitic = Table[Evaluate[ASolution[[1]]][i], {i, 0, 1, 0.1}]
y1numeric = Table[Evaluate[NSolution[[1]]][i], {i, 0, 1, 0.1}]
y1difference = y1analitic - y1numeric
y1norm = y1difference /y1analitic
```

Questions:

1. How to find stability function for this case of RK4? Is there a default fucntion for that?
2. How to display plot which represents stability region?
3. If I want use different numerical methods to solve DAE (not RK4, but RK5 for example or another coefficients for RK order 4) and get the similar answers for the questions above, how can i do that automatically? I just want compare

P.S. All that I found now is tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest#969193662

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The simplest way to find stability function is to use formula $$R(z)=\frac{Det[I-z\times A+z\times e\times b^T]}{Det[I-z\times A]}$$ where $A$ is Runge-Kutta matrix and $b$ is weights (*Butcher tableau*).`R = Det[MI - z*A + z*ME.Transpose[B]]/Det[MI - z*A]`
   In Wolfram Mathematica we could do that by using the function `RungeKuttaLinearStabilityFunction`
2. For displaying plot which represents stability region we can use `OrderStarPlot` from FunctionApproximations.